# How do you have different settings per app in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-settings

How do you have different settings per app in Django? For example, I have 2 apps:

- internal_api
- external_api

They need different settings for the expiration delta of a JWT token.  I'm using a `django-rest-framework` add-on called [djangorestframework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt)

internal_api needs settings of:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=12),
}
```

external_api needs settings of:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
}
```

Comment: Why not create two different settings within the same settings file, one called JWT_AUTH_EXT and the other JWT_AUTH_INT (or something along those lines)?

Comment: because when `djangorestframework-jwt` initializes the settings it only looks  for adding settings called `JWT_AUTH`, anything else would not get imported into the settings.  https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/settings.py#L7  line 53 shows where those settings are stored as `api_settings`.  Those `api_settings` are then the settings that the rest of the library refers to...

Answer (score 2):

You can `import` the Django settings in a module-specific way at run time in the specific app where you need it to. You do this by:

```
from django.conf import settings
from internal_api import internal_api_settings
settings.configure(default_settings=internal_api_settings)
```

Where `internal_api_settings` will be a module in `internal_api` that specifies the `JWT_AUTH` values. I believe you can be even more specific in your `settings.configure()` call and actually specify:

```
settings.configure(JWT_AUTH=internal_api_settings.settings_dictionary)
```

Where `settings_dictionary` is the value you want passed into the settings.

Comment: I tried the above but get `RuntimeError: Settings already configured.`  Also, Django docs say not to do this...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

Comment: see also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#either-configure-or-django-settings-module-is-required

Comment: I believe it's okay if you use a settings.py in your app directories. They mostly just don't want you doing this your views.

Comment: `settings.configure` can only be run once.  It can't be run even in a `settings.py` file.  In doing so, it would also rewrite the settings for the rest of the application.